# Magento - dynamic pricing

Tags: magento, dynamic, product

I have created a simple e-commerce application that calculates a price based on many options.

The price is calculated in PHP based on a bunch of variables stored in MySQL.  I have coded the PHP as a web service which I use jQuery AJAX to query.

I need to integrate this into a client's existing e-commerce site, which is using Magento.

I want to allow customers to add my "dynamic priced product" to their cart.  I need to be able to add the custom price along with the product information (which I am happy to have in a single hidden field).

I am familiar with programming (client and server side, most languages) but I am not at all familiar with Magento.  Is there a simple way of achieving this?  Ideally I would add the information to an existing form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to create a product in magento to use as a template.

Then create a observer

```
<events>
    <sales_quote_add_item>
        <observers>
            <priceupdate_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                <method>updatePrice</method>
            </priceupdate_observer>
        </observers>
    </sales_quote_add_item>
</events>
```

Then in your observer method you does something like this:

```
public function updatePrice($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
    $new_price = <insert logic to check if this is the custom product and to get value from ajax>
    $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
    $quote_item->save();
}
```

(note that a user could always fake the post and change the item price)

See [Customize Magento using Event/Observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be exactly what I want!  I am aware that someone could "spoof" the value but it will get re-checked when the admin user looks it up.